# Computer froze during Ubuntu install and now computer won't post and no BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bios

A few minutes ago I was installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my Windows 7 machine and it froze during the installation. I waited awhile then rebooted. Now the monitors never turn on and the BIOS never shows. It just keeps rapidly rebooting. :/

I'm not sure how this could be a hardware issue since all I was doing was installing the OS. The computer was not moved at all. My motherboard is an MSI Z77MA-G45 with an Intel i7.

Thanks

Comment: Does your system have uEFI with secure boot?

Comment: I actually don't remember. :) I'm not familiar with that. I've been trying to reset the CMOS but still nothing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what "bios never shows" means. But I'm sure, your BIOS did not change after the failed Ubuntu installation. But your MBR did. Now boot to your Windows 7 DVD, and then enter Recovery mode (not install again), wait for a while, log on to your account (enter your W7 account and then your account's password), enter "fixmbr" without quote, press enter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, "bios never shows" actually doesn't make any sense, sorry!(i was tired) Unfortunately, I think my mother board bricked. I pulled everything off the motherboard except a stick of memory, the power and the cpu and it still kept rebooting every few seconds. It seems like the CPU phase never finishes. So off to buy another board... Oh well. Thanks again!